# SOLVED - Where is my PayPal Payment Data Transfer (PDT) Identity Token? 2020

Tags: paypal

I spent HOURS searching for the PDT identity token in my PayPal account. Every result provided instructions relating to PayPal's old view, which apparently was updated recently.

To find your PDT identity token, click on the action gear in the upper right corner next to the Log Out button. Select **Account Settings > Website Payments > Website Preferences > Update**. Then scroll down to "Payment data transfer (optional)" and you'll see your Identity Token.

[Website Payments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpes1.png)
[Identity Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKXxt.png)

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the instructions for obtaining a PDT identity token are out of date. I'd guess this is in part because using PDT for anything important is 15 years out of date.

PDT is completely unreliable, because returns are never guaranteed to happen, due to browser/network crashes or the customer not waiting for the auto-return (there is a timer) or not clicking through to return (typically guests w/o an account must be shown a receipt and click to return). So PDT is suitable for informational purposes only (e.g. showing buyers a thank you message when they *do* return.).

Absolutely no business logic should depend on a PDT return actually occurring. Instead, if you need a dependable notification from PayPal of payment completion, an asynchronous IPN or one of the newer webhooks should be listened for -- or alternatively, the integration should be changed to a more robust synchronous server-side one such as this pattern: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , where there is always an immediate API response on payment capture for notification purposes.

TL;DR it's a super old web 1.0 thing and nearly worthless in 2020.. still around for backwards compatibility, not because it makes sense to use.

Comment: So I've already got the IPN happening, I just thought adding the optional PDT would be another way to help ensure a positive customer experience. I'm foggy on how it's actually going to play out. Testing next. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Ah, well for the most positive customer experience I'd recommend the newest checkout which doesn't use PDT at all.  There's a client-side version if you don't want to do server API calls for some reason: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client. (but the server pattern with v2/orders is more robust, if you can implement it)